# Argparse conditionally add arguments with base flags

Tags: python, argparse

I want to create a parser for jobs with their params. Each job has varying kinds of arguments, except every job has to have a date argument.

What I want:

```
script.py --job base_job_name --date today
script.py --job similar_job --date today --additional_input_location /path/to/file
```

What I have

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("-j", "--job", choices=jobs)
parser.add_argument("-d", "--date", type=validate_date, required=True)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

specific_job_parser = subparsers.add_parser(specific_job_name, parents=[parser])
specific_job_parser.add_argument("-a", "--additional_input_location")
```

This setup forces me to create an ugly CLI like `script.py --job specific_job --date $date specific_job -a /file/path`

How can I get closer to `script.py --job specific_job --date $date -a /file/path` and `script.py --job base_job --date $date`

Comment: How are you using the arguments? Are you feeding them to a function that chooses some function to call based on the `job` argument? Because you should be able to pass the full parsed args to any function. It sounds like you may want to not use the `--job` argument but use the power of the subparsers to know which command you need to call, and then each command has their own specific arguments.

Comment: BTW, note that `--additional-input-location`, with dashes instead of underscores, would be more conventional.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a straightforward `subparsers`?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
# parser.add_argument("-j", "--job", choices=jobs)
parser.add_argument("-d", "--date", type=validate_date, required=True)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='jobs')

specific_job_parser = subparsers.add_parser(specific_job_name)
specific_job_parser.add_argument("-a", "--additional_input_location")
```

This should accept

```
script.py --date $date specific_job -a /file/path
script.py --date $date base_job
```

Alternatively omit the `--date` from the main parser, and add it each of the subparsers - yes that will require more typing, but better something that works.

Don't use the main parser as parent to the subparsers.  You could use a separate parser that's written specifically for the purpose.  The subparsers mechanism does not work well you try to put the same argument in both the main parser and the subparsers.  Put it in one place or the other, not both.